# PHP Codes After Caching [How to]

Tags: php, caching, ob-start

I have a problem in my php codes. I'am using a simple cache system with this function.

```
// Cache Function
function cachestart($min){
    global $here;
    global $cachefile;
    $cachedosyasi = 'cache/' . 'file' . md5($here);
    if(file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $min*60 < filemtime($cachefile))){
    include($cachefile);
    die;
    }else{
        ob_start();
        global $cache;
        $cache = 1;
    }
}

function cachefinish(){
    global $cache;
    global $cachefile;
    if(@$cache){
        $ch = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
        fwrite($ch, ob_get_contents());
        fclose($ch);
        ob_end_flush(); 
    }
}
```

I'am trying that:

```
-- Some Queries (Controls, is user logged etc. )
<< Start Caching >> (With cachestart() )
-- Some Queries (Show entries in database. )
<< Stop Caching >> (With cachefinish() )
-- Some Queries (Comment box)
```

But i can't this because of "die". I don't have an idea about it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: All queries work again, and I see double everything between cache functions. 

Edit: Someone said "delete 'die' in function", but comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this isn't perfect, but using your existing code; just return `true` or `false` and have your application make decisions based on that:

```
function cachestart($min){
    global $cachefile;
    if(file_exists($cachefile) && (time() - $min*60 < filemtime($cachefile))){
        include($cachefile);
        //we are not caching
        return false;
    } else {
        ob_start();
        //we are caching
        return true;
    }
}
```

Make a decision at the start of your application:

```
if(!cachestart(60)) {
    //page loaded from cache
    //maybe do some queries for comment box
    die(); //or call cachefinish() with a die() in there
}

//main application code
```